# Space above and below viewpager

Tags: android, slider

I have a layout with an image slider (viewpager ) and few recyclerviews. There is spave above and below the viewpager even though I have removed all padding and margins from everywhere. Where is this coming from? I have checked my child item for the viewpager adapter. There are no margins or padding there as well. Any help is appreciated.

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_home"
tools:context=".java.Home.HomeFragment">


  <include
    android:id="@+id/banner"
    layout="@layout/banner_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


  <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/banner"
   />



   <include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/card_home_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_pager"
    />

     <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    style="@style/MySubTitleFont"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/popular_countries"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include"
  />

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"      


    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"/>
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Change this attribute of view pager `android:layout_height="220dp"` to `android:layout_height="0dp"` & provide it bottom constraint also.

Answer (score 0):

please use ConstraintLayout as parent layout and NestedScrollView as a child of ConstraintLayout :-
you have defined following paramas these are nothing but margins try removing following params

> android:layout_marginStart="4dp"    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
>       android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"